# how to interactive with geth frequently?

Tags: light-clients

```
mHandler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

            BigInt bBalance = new BigInt(0);
            try {
                Address address = new Address(addressString);
                mEthereumClient.getBalanceAt(mContext, address, DEFAULT_TO_CURRENT_BLOCK_VALUE);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                DerbyLog.LogError("getBalanceAt " + e.getMessage().toString());
            }

          //每隔1s循环执行run方法
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(r,100);
```

this code will stop with unknown reason   why?

Comment: What do you mean with "stop with unknown reason"? This code looks like it should work. What do you pass  in for DEFAULT_TO_CURRENT_BLOCK_VALUE

Comment: the DEFAULT_TO_CURRENT_BLOCK_VALUE   value is  -1

Comment: the mean is  when i call getbalanceat it can not receive anything .......

Comment: Are you fully synced?

Comment: i am sure    cause i don't known how to add event in android light client   so have to use this method to call frequently

Comment: You cout use subscirbeNewHead like this: https://github.com/walleth/walleth/blob/master/app/src/withGeth/java/org/walleth/geth/services/GethLightEthereumService.kt#L168
How did you verify you are fully synced?

Comment: i need to call about balanceof and other 5 self contract  method  ..........your mean  i can put all of the request method in the newheadhandle function?

Comment: sure - it is just a trigger - you can put everything in there - but really depends on your use-case

Comment: You are very welcome - good luck and let me know when you run into problems